# How do I choose multiple minimum values in a dictionary?

Tags: python, dictionary

I'm trying to inspect and choose values in a dictionary if they're the same minimum values from the whole dictionary.

As you can see, my code is choosing duplicate values although they're not the minimum values. How do i correct this error? For example, my code shouldn't't delete values (including duplicates) unless there are multiple '7.14'

```
     def tieBreaker (preDictionary):
        while True:
            minValues = min(preDictionary.values())
            minKeys = [k for k in preDictionary if preDictionary[k] == minValues]
            print(minKeys)

            for i in range(0, len(minKeys)):
                for j in range(0, len(minKeys)):

                    if minKeys[i] > minKeys[j]:
                        del preDictionary[minKeys[i]]
                        i += 1
                        j += 1

            if len(minKeys) < 2:

                return preDictionary
                break
```

Current output is {'candidate1': '35.71', 'candidate2': '28.57', 'candidate4': '14.29', 'candidate3': '7.14'}

While the input is {'candidate1': '35.71', 'candidate2': '28.57', 'candidate5': '14.29', 'candidate4': '14.29', 'candidate3': '7.14'}

candidate 5 should not be deleted as although it's a duplicate value, not a minimum..

Also, minKeys currently is ['candidate5', 'candidate4'] where it should be ['candidate3']

Comment: Paste the code man, the image doesn't help that much

Comment: Your image is cropped, the results are not visible. Please put some effort to at least post your code. Also share your inputs, outputs and expected outputs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not need a `while` loop. You can run through each key value pair and construct a new `dict` without the keys with minimum value.

```
d = {'candidate1': 35.71, 'candidate2': 28.57, 'candidate4': 14.29, 'candidate3': 7.14}
min_value = min(d.values())

d_without_min_value = {k: v for k, v in d.items() if v != min_value}

# output
# {'candidate1': 35.71, 'candidate2': 28.57, 'candidate4': 14.29}
```

**EDIT**

**Seems like you are passing values as string instead of `float`.** Calling `min()` on a `list` of `str` will result in minimum value in [lexicographical order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexicographic_order). Remove the quotes around the values or convert the values into `float` before you process the dict

```
d = {k: float(v) for k, v in d.items()}
```